# Iterating through a list using function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate through a list in python and printing it with the word 'hello' after it. However, I am not getting the desired output.

The code reads a text file which has numeric ID's. I have created a list of the read ID and used a for loop to iterate through it. Following is my code:

```
def read_file():
 pmid_s = []
 file_object = open("file.txt", "r", encoding='cp1252')
 pmid =file_object.read()
 pmid_s.append(pmid)
 for pmid in pmid_s:
    return(pmid)

def driver(pmid):
 print("hello"+pmid) 

def main():
 pmid= read_file
 driver(pmid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The desired output is as follows in new line:

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
hello5
```

Comment: What output do you get? Why are you calling `driver` instead of `print`? And why are you redefining the `print` function?!

Comment: You just appending the whole bunch to the list, i.e. one big string returned by `read()`. You could try `pmid_s = list(file_object)`. This is going to give you the lines.

Comment: What exactly is `read_file` supposed to do? You read the entire contents into one variable, append that to an empty list, then iterate over the singleton list. The entire function could be simplified to `read_file = lambda: open(...).read()`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Apologies, I have edited the code.

Comment: @chepner the function read_file is supposed to read data from a text file and append it to an empty list which needs to be iterated for the print function to print hello+pmid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file consisting of a series of integers, one per line. A file iterator yields the lines of the file. You can build the list by iterating over the file itself.

```
def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r", encoding='cp1252') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

def driver(s):
    print("hello" + s)

def main():
    for num in read_file("file.txt"):
        driver(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

If you want to do it lazily, make `read_file` a generator function.

```
def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r", encoding='cp1252') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()
```

This only ever reads a single line of the file into memory at a time, when a consumer tries to read the next item from the resulting generator.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use driver(pmid) instead of return(pmid). 
Also you can split what you read directly using the split() method, and there's no need to append after that. See below:

```
def read_file():
    pmid_s = []
    file_object = open("file.txt", "r", encoding='cp1252')
    pmid_s =file_object.read().split()
    for pmid in pmid_s:
        driver(pmid)


def driver(pmid):
    print("hello {} \n ".format(pmid))


def main():
    pmid= read_file()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm also assuming that the numbers you read are separated by space

Comment: You might want to actually run your code and verify that it does what is expected before posting it.

Comment: Just some reformatting of your program @ionut, and you're there! Yes! Now your program runs! Well done.